# Is it possible to call a scala macro from generic scala code?

Tags: scala, generics, macros, metaprogramming, parametric-polymorphism

I'm trying to use Scala macros to convert untyped, `Map[String, Any]`-like expressions to their corresponding typed case class expressions.

The following scala macro (almost) gets the job done:

```scala
trait ToTyped[+T] {
  def apply(term: Any): T
}

object TypeConversions {
  // At compile-time, "type-check" an untyped expression and convert it to 
  // its appropriate typed value.
  def toTyped[T]: ToTyped[T] = macro toTypedImpl[T]

  def toTypedImpl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context): c.Expr[ToTyped[T]] = {
    import c.universe._
    val tpe = weakTypeOf[T]

    if (tpe <:< typeOf[Int] || tpe <:< typeOf[String]) {
      c.Expr[ToTyped[T]](
        q"""new ToTyped[$tpe] { 
          def apply(term: Any): $tpe = term.asInstanceOf[$tpe] 
        }""")
    } else {
      val companion = tpe.typeSymbol.companion
      val maybeConstructor = tpe.decls.collectFirst { 
        case m: MethodSymbol if m.isPrimaryConstructor => m 
      }
      val constructorFields = maybeConstructor.get.paramLists.head

      val subASTs = constructorFields.map { field =>
        val fieldName = field.asTerm.name
        val fieldDecodedName = fieldName.toString
        val fieldType = tpe.decl(fieldName).typeSignature
        q"""
           val subTerm = term.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]($fieldDecodedName)
           TypeConversions.toTyped[$fieldType](subTerm)
        """
      }
      c.Expr[ToTyped[T]](
        q"""new ToTyped[$tpe] { 
          def apply(term: Any): $tpe = $companion(..$subASTs) 
        }""")
    }
  }
}
```

Using the above `toTyped` function, I can convert for example an untyped person value to its corresponding typed `Person` case class:

```scala
object TypeConversionTests {
  case class Person(name: String, age: Int, address: Address)
  case class Address(street: String, num: Int, zip: Int)

  val untypedPerson = Map(
    "name" -> "Max",
    "age" -> 27,
    "address" -> Map("street" -> "Palm Street", "num" -> 7, "zip" -> 12345))
  val typedPerson = TypeConversions.toTyped[Person](untypedPerson)

  typedPerson shouldEqual Person("Max", 27, Address("Palm Street", 7, 12345))
}
```

However, my problem arises when trying to use the `toTyped` macro from above in generic scala code. Suppose I have a generic function `indirection` that uses the `toTyped` macro:

```scala
object CanIUseScalaMacrosAndGenerics {
  def indirection[T](value: Any): T = TypeConversions.toTyped[T](value)

  import TypeConversionTests._

  val indirectlyTyped = indirection[Person](untypedPerson)

  indirectlyTyped shouldEqual Person("Max", 27, Address("Palm Street", 7, 12345))
```

Here, I get a compile-time error from the `toTyped` macro complaining that the type `T` is not yet instantiated with a concrete type. I think the reason for the error is that from the perspective of `toTyped` inside `indirection`, the type `T` is still generic and not inferred to be `Person` just yet. And therefore the macro cannot build the corresponding `Person` case class when called via `indirection`. However, from the perspective of the call-site `indirection[Person](untypedPerson)`, we have `T == Person`, so I wonder if there is a way to obtain the instantiated type of `T` (i.e., `Person`) inside the macro `toTyped`.

Put differently: Can I combine the Scala macro `toTyped` with the generic function `indirection` and yet be able to figure out the instantiated type for type parameter `T` inside the `toTyped` macro? Or am I on a hopeless track here and there is no way to combine Scala macros and generics like this? In the latter case I would like to know if the only solution here is to push the macro usage so far "out" that I can call it instantiated as `toTyped[Person]` rather than as `toTyped[T]`.

Any insights are very much appreciated. Thank you! :-)

Comment: Try `def indirection[T: TypeTag](value: Any): T`.

Comment: As @AlexeyRomanov mentioned but since you are using `WeakTypeTag` in his macro impl... so better to provide a `WeakTypeTag` instead of `TypeTag`

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh WeakTypeTag will allow exactly the same problem when you call `indirection` from another generic method.  But https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/788478d3ab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Macros need to be expanded. Every time you use a function which body is a macro, Scala will have to generate the code and put it there. As you suspect, this is very very specific and contradict the idea of parametric polymorphism where you write code independent of specific knowledge about your type.

Type classes are one of solutions to the general problem when you want to have one generic (parametric) definition and multiple per-type implementations of certain parts of your algorithm. You basically, define something that you could consider interface which (most likely) need to follow some contract (speaking in OOP terminology) and pass this interface as as argument:

```scala
// example
trait SpecificPerType[T] {

  def doSomethingSpecific(t: T): String
}

val specificForString: SpecificPerType[String] = new SpecificPerType[String] {
  def doSomethingSpecific(t: String): String = s"MyString: $t"
}

val specificForInt: SpecificPerType[Int] = new SpecificPerType[Int] {
  def doSomethingSpecific(t: Int): String = s"MyInt: $t"
}

def genericAlgorithm[T](values: List[T])(specific: SpecificPerType[T]): String =
  values.map(specific.doSomethingSpecific).mkString("\n")

genericAlgorithm(List(1,2,3))(specificForInt)
genericAlgorithm(List("a","b","c"))(specificForString)
```

As you can see, it would be pretty annoying to pass this specific part around, which is one of the reasons implicits were introduced.

So you could write it using implicits like this:

```scala
implicit val specificForString: SpecificPerType[String] = new SpecificPerType[String] {
  def doSomethingSpecific(t: String): String = s"MyString: $t"
}

implicit val specificForInt: SpecificPerType[Int] = new SpecificPerType[Int] {
  def doSomethingSpecific(t: Int): String = s"MyInt: $t"
}

def genericAlgorithm[T](values: List[T])(implicit specific: SpecificPerType[T]): String =
  values.map(specific.doSomethingSpecific).mkString("\n")
/* for implicits with one type parameter there exist a special syntax
   allowing to express them as if they were type constraints e.g.:

def genericAlgorithm[T: SpecificPerType](values: List[T]): String =
  values.map(implicitly[SpecificPerType[T]].doSomethingSpecific).mkString("\n")

implicitly[SpecificPerType[T]] is a summoning that let you access implicit
by type, rather than by its variable's name
*/

genericAlgorithm(List(1,2,3)) // finds specificForString using its type
genericAlgorithm(List("a","b","c")) // finds specificForInt using its type
```

If you generate that trait implementation using macro, you will be able to have a generic algorithm e.g.:

```scala
implicit def generate[T]: SpecificPerType[T] =
  macro SpecificPerTypeMacros.impl // assuming that you defined this macro there
```

As far as I can tell, this (extracting macros into type classes) is one of common patterns when it comes to being
able to generate some code with macros while, still building logic on top of it
using normal, parametric code.

(Just to be clear: I do not claim that the role of type classes is limited as the carriers of macro generated code).

Comment: thanks Mateusz for your detailed reply! I'll try to use the type class approach then.